# how to use html2canvas and jspdf to export to pdf in a proper and simple way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jspdf

I am currently working on a school management software that usually requires exporting of html contents that contains `data tables` and `div tag`.

I have tried all possible means to write a code that will be able to export my html data in a good way, with css preferably. After checking some question and answers here, I tried using spdf, but no luck.

It keeps destroying my table alignment, then I read about `html2canvas` but to implement it with `jspdf` was my problem, i would like to capture the content if a div tag with `html2canvas` then send the canvas to `jspdf` to export the canvas as pdf.

Here is my code below:

```
<script src="assets/js/pdfconvert/jspdf.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/pdfconvert/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/pdfconvert/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/pdfconvert/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js">  </script>
<script src="assets/js/pdfconvert/jspdf.plugin.addhtml.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/pdfconvert/filesaver.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/pdfconvert/jspdf.plugin.cell.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/pdfconvert/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/pdfconvert/jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script>
```

here is the js code

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
pdf.addHTML($('#ElementYouWantToConvertToPdf')[0], function () {
pdf.save('Test.pdf');
});
```

Comment: Are you able to show the div on the canvas using html2canvas?

Comment: no i cant, the above jquery code does nothing when i run it

Comment: please i need help or suggestions

Comment: I wrote you the code to convert the html to an image to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/mj3hhxvs/ From here on you need it to convert it to pdf using jspdf. Look at the documentation

Comment: thanks, what is the page is much longer.. how can you split it?

Comment: Create different containers for each section (in my example it would be "element-to-render") and then render each of those to a different canvas, create different images and add all of them to your pdf

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have made a jsfiddle for you.

```
 <canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas> 
      <button id="download">Download Pdf</button>
```

'

```
        html2canvas($("#canvas"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {         
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                    'image/png');              
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
                doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
            }
        });
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rpaul/p4s5k59s/5/

Tested  in Chrome38, IE11 and Firefox 33. Seems to have issues with Safari. However, Andrew got it working in Safari 8 on Mac OSx by switching to JPEG from PNG. For details, see his comment below.

Comment: Sweet! This works great in Chrome. In Safari, though, I just get a blank page when I click the download button.

Comment: Thanks Andrerw. Is is Safari 5.1.7? It seems Safari version 6 and 7 does not support windows? JSpdf has some issues with safari.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755171/jspdf-not-working-on-safari Have you tried doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');?

Comment: I tested it in Safari 8 on OS X. I'm wondering if the issue might be with saving the canvas data as PNG data. I was having issues getting things to work in Safari on a project I'm working on, but then I switched to JPEG and it suddenly started working.

Comment: If i have two canvas i.e canvas1 and canvas2 and want to export to in a single pdf using the html2canvas, than what will be the code ?? help me..Please

Comment: @Ananta, one option is to put the both canvases inside a div and use the div ID in html2canvas call.

Comment: If i dont want to put canvases inside a div , then ??

Comment: Another option is making separate html2canvas call with each canvas and  onrendered method, converting the canvases to images. Then, adding two images using doc.addImage method to the pdf. Note: you need to use promise here to make sure that both image conversions have been completed before you call doc.save method.

Comment: IT WORKS PERFECT! THANKS

Comment: I get the following errors on the jsfiddle: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` then `parall.ax/products/jspdf/dist/jspdf.debug.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` and then `(index):93 Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined(…)`

Comment: How can I add a loader as soon the user clicks the button?

Comment: it throws: onrendered option is deprecated

Comment: What should i do if i want to save pdf file on my custom path.

Comment: How we can add the page split automatically based on height of page?

Comment: jsfiddle Uncaught ReferenceError: html2canvas is not defined

Answer (score 13):

This one shows how to print only selected element on the page with `dpi/resolution` adjustments

HTML:

```
<html>

  <body>
    <header>This is the header</header>
    <div id="content">
      This is the element you only want to capture
    </div>
    <button id="print">Download Pdf</button>
    <footer>This is the footer</footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: beige;
}

header {
  background: red;
}

footer {
  background: blue;
}

#content {
  background: yellow;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#print').click(function() {

  var w = document.getElementById("content").offsetWidth;
  var h = document.getElementById("content").offsetHeight;
  html2canvas(document.getElementById("content"), {
    dpi: 300, // Set to 300 DPI
    scale: 3, // Adjusts your resolution
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
      var doc = new jsPDF('L', 'px', [w, h]);
      doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0, w, h);
      doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    }
  });
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/marksalvania/dum8bfco/

Comment: Replace "L" with 'l'.

Answer (score 1):

Changing this line:

```
var doc = new jsPDF('L', 'px', [w, h]);
var doc = new jsPDF('L', 'pt', [w, h]);
```

To fix the dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

This worked when you add "useCORS: true".
Grabs google map as it is rendered on the screen and puts it in a pdf

```
function create_pdf() {
         return html2canvas($('#map'), {
             useCORS: true,
             background: "#ffffff",
             onrendered: function(canvas) {
                 var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg,1.0");
                 // Adjust width and height
                 var imgWidth =  (canvas.width * 60) / 240;
                 var imgHeight = (canvas.height * 70) / 240;
                 // jspdf changes
                 var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
                 pdf.addImage(myImage, 'png', 15, 2, imgWidth, imgHeight); // 2: 19
                 pdf.save(`Budgeting ${$('.pdf-title').text()}.pdf`);
             }
         });
```