# download html5 canvas as pdf(safari browser)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, jspdf

I want to download canvas as PDF.I have a code that works on all browsers except safari.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
pdf.addImage(dt, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
pdf.save("download.pdf");
```

On Safari, it opens the PDF in new window. I want the PDF to get downloaded directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jsPDF not working on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755171/jspdf-not-working-on-safari)

Comment: Also, please check the [issue](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/697) on GitHub about this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755171/jspdf-not-working-on-safari
is not a solution.The solution here opens the pdf in the same tab.It does not download automatically

Comment: What version of Safari? Works for me on 11.1 They did implement 'download'  attribute quite recently though. Also, you might be interested by the fact Safari does support `canvas.toBlob(callback, 'application/pdf')` and `canvas.toDataURL('application/pdf')` directly.

Comment: The best solution is to pass the canvas to server as jpg.Make a pdf with the image on server side and then download from server.